# MySQL Rejecting Query Syntax Based on Apostrophe Character

Tags: php, mysql

I am using MeekroDB (http://www.meekro.com/quickstart.php) to construct simple MySQL queries in PHP. Even simple queries are being rejected due to incorrect syntax. I noticed by writing queries manually in phpMyAdmin that queries are rejected if they use this syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM 'table name'
```

But accepted if they use this syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM `table name`
```

The only difference is a slightly different apostrophe. MeekroDB seems to be producing the first syntax by default, which is causing the queries to be rejected. Has anyone faced this before? Any solutions? I'm using WAMP Server and MySQL 5.5.24.

Note: Queries generated by MeekroDB are working if they do not contain an apostrophe or if the second apostrophe type is inserted manually. So:

```
$result = DB::query("SELECT DISTINCT `column` FROM `table`")
```

works but:

```
$result = DB::query("SELECT DISTINCT %s FROM %s", "column","table")
```

doesn't.

Comment: Don't use tools/tutorials that teach the old deprecated MySQL library.... learn MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements

Comment: Learn about the three types of quotes and when/where to use them.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario MeekroDB allows you to use placeholders in query strings (see link to quickstart) but then seems to enclose them in the wrong kind of quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hadn't heard about MeekroDB but it appears to be a simple database abstraction layer. Your second example:

```
$result = DB::query("SELECT DISTINCT %s FROM %s", "column","table")
```

... is invalid because neither "column" nor "table" are literal strings you want to inject. They're column/table names that are part of the SQL statement, not user-provided parameters.

This is a basic concept in most programming languages. `SELECT foo` is different from `SELECT 'foo'` in SQL for the same reason that `echo md5(1);` is different from `echo 'md5(1)';` in PHP.

**Update:**

I suspect I wasn't clear enough. Using prepared statements to bind language constructs or object names is a misuse of any database library, MeekroDB or not. You are supposed to bind parameters that represent **values**, esp. those entered by end users, so you the value does not leak into SQL and breaks the query or change its meaning. But there're normally no tools to inject SQL **commands** or **table names**—they'd be of little use: if you allow the user to build arbitrary SQL queries, he's already been granted the power to do almost anything he wants.

Comment: @alvaro OK, so just to be clear though, this likely is a problem with the MeekroDB framework itself and not my use of it?

Answer (score -4):

Well since PHP doesn't treat strings the same way other languages do this is a somewhat bad idea. In essence they have tried to make it easier for developers but doesn't always happen. In reality what you could do is

```
$result = DB::query(sprintf("SELECT DISTINCT %s FROM %s", "column","table"));
```

Comment: PHP doesn't treat strings the same way other languages do? What do you mean?

Comment: I mean variables in general. It is far less strict compared to other languages such as c or java. I'm not a big fan of sprint either since in my experience it tends to be a slow solution, even though it is in general safe to use.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean, but `%s` in this context is not a `printf()` format code, it's MeekroDB's syntax for prepared statements. Your answer is wrong because it doesn't point out the base error and it even suggests replacing bind parameters with... well, with nothing.